# How to get attribute "option label/attribute text" having "attribute value" (option_id)?

Tags: attributes, collection, eav

Suppose I have an attribute that is a collection of option (dropdown/multiselect).

I can retrieve the attribute value for a given product:

```
$store_id = [something];
$productId = [something];
// this is a select/multiselect
$attribute_code = [something]; 

$option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, $attribute_code, $store_id );
$option_label = ???
```

Now, I got the attribute option_id which is a numeric value ...

... What is the best way to load the frontend attribute label for my attribute value ? (without loading the full product)

**Solution** thanks [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius):

```
// Not loading the product - just creating a simple instance
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->setStoreId($store_id)
->setData($attribute_code,$option_id); 
$option_label = $product->getAttributeText($attribute_code);
```

Comment: Why this question is given several times by exact author and all of them confusing users. Can we mark as duplicate like these questions without correct answers? This http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3003 question given by the author is no correct answers, but why upvotes (and given own answer)! This one http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/976 is also same. Maybe my request is not right, but one question, one author and no answers. Please, keep the quality of the site. Thanks.

Comment: I have improved the other question adding @Marius solution http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3003/get-product-attribute-option-label

Comment: Note that at least in Magento CE 1.9 and EE 1.14 and below, `getAttributeText('value')` doesn't work correctly if the attribute's `getAllOptions()` method returns options arranged with nested arrays, (expressed as an `<optgroup>` in the dropdown.)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In addition to your code put this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($store_id)
                ->setBrand($brand_value); // not loading the product - just creating a simple instance
$brandLabel = $product->getAttributeText('brand');
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
            ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer');
$label     = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
```

Comment: I confused for "frontend attribute label", please, correct the question. Not "attribute label", this is "option label" or "attribute text"