# Get Option Value by Id of Attribute in Magento

Tags: product, attributes, model, search

How can Magento find an attribute *value* by a given attribute label or a given attribute id?

Comment: I believe this is answered by another SO question seen [here]( http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8396)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute "option label/attribute text" having "attribute value" (option\_id)?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8394/how-to-get-attribute-option-label-attribute-text-having-attribute-value-opt)

Answer (score 17):

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$str_attr_label = "color";  //or "size", etc...
$int_attr_id = 8; // or any given id.
$int_attr_value = 21; // or any given attribute value id.

// Chose either
if ($byLabel){
    $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute($str_attr_label);
}
if ($byId){
    $attr = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($int_attr_id);
}

if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    echo $color_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($int_attr_value);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply put - use the **getAttributeText** method.

```
$product->getAttributeText('brand')
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: this was so difficult to find, yet so simple.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone finds this page and wants some down low methods of looking up attributes of any kind, instead of just product attributes, here is an example to look up a random attribute I created that is called 'specialty' and list all the options as an array.

```
$attr = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter('specialty')->getData()[0];
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attr['attribute_id']);
$src =  $attributeModel->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```