# getAttributeRawValue gives an id

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I'm trying to compare an attribute value with a custom value. 
We use the `getAttributeRawValue` to get the product's attribute. That give's me the ID of the value. (If that makes sense).

Currently I use this line:

```
$col = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($simp, 'manufacturer_color', 0);`
```

Attribute with code `manufacturer_color` is of **type Select**

which outputs `1587`, I want it to output the 'label' value which in my case should be `blue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it using `getAttributeText()` function and **this function will only work with the attribute type `select`**

```
$col=$simp->getAttributeText('manufacturer_color');
```

`getAttributeRawValue()` **returns the id of options**

OR

```
$col=$simp->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer_color')->getFrontend()->getValue($simp);
```

Comment: Getting `Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in` gi es an error.. Any idea?

Comment: `getAttributeText` will only work if your attribute is of **type select** @xvilo

Comment: Not sure where to find *type select*. the *input type* is on `dropdown`

Comment: yes select is nothing but dropdown only. Then it must be work @xvilo

Comment: Bút, it doesn't.

Comment: @xvilo try my updated code and make sure `$simp` is product object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54319/discussion-between-xvilo-and-gopal-patel).

Comment: The first option gives me boolean, the second gives me a string with "No" as a content. Magento, everything is clear as always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAttributeText` to get product label.

```
$label = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($simp)->getAttributeText("manufacturer_name");
```

You can use as per Marius's [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8396/2443) like,

```
$col = \Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($simp, 'manufacturer_color', 0);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->setStoreId(0)
     ->setData('manufacturer_color',$col); 
$optionLabel = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer_color');
```

Comment: Getting `Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in` gi es an error.. Any idea?